# Can a script be used as an interpreter by the #! hashbang line?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, system-administration

I'm trying to write a bash script which will behave as a basic interpreter, but it doesn't seem to work: The custom interpreter doesn't appear to be invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a simple setup illustrating the problem:

`/bin/interpreter`: [owned by root; executable]

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I am an interpreter running " $1
```

`/Users/zeph/script` is owned by me, and is executable:

```
#!/bin/interpreter

Here are some commands for the custom interpreter.
```

From what I understand about the mechanics of hashbangs, the script should be executable as follows:

```
$ ./script
I am an interpreter running ./script
```

But this doesn't work. Instead the following happens:

```
$ ./script 
./script: line 3: Here: command not found
```

...It appears that `/bin/bash` is trying to interpret the contents of `./script`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Although it appears that `/bin/interpreter` never invoked, I *do* get an error if it doesn't exist:

```
$ ./script
-bash: ./script: /bin/interpreter: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

(Second note: If it makes any difference, I'm doing this on MacOS X).

Comment: Can you please add the result of `ls -al /bin/interpreter`

Comment: The result of `ls -al /bin/interpreter` is: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  63  9 Jul 12:22 /bin/interpreter`

Comment: Try `strace ./script` (e.g. using `strace ./script 2>&1 | less`) to see what's going on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make this work you could add the interpreter's interpreter (i.e. `bash`) to the shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash /bin/interpreter

Here are some commands for the custom interpreter.
```

`bash` will then run your interpreter with the script path in `$1` as expected.

Comment: Both `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/env` work as binary launchers for the interpreter. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a script *directly* as a `#!` interpreter, but you can run the script indirectly via the `env` command using:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env /bin/interpreter
```

`/usr/bin/env` is itself a binary, so is a valid interpreter for `#!`; and `/bin/interpreter` can be anything you like (a script of any variety, or binary) without having to put knowledge of its own interpreter into the calling script.

Answer (score 4):

Read the `execve` man page for your system. It dictates how scripts are launched, and it should specify that the interpreter in a hash-bang line is a binary executable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Both `man execve` and `man 3 exec` mention nothing specific on OS X 10.6 about the interpreter needing to be binary, but nevertheless this appears to be the issue at heart. There are surprisingly few Google results for similar problems, though!

Answer (score 0):

I asked [a similar question in comp.unix.shell](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.unix.shell/56MwY0LAGEc/discussion) that raised some pertinent information.

There was [a second branch of the same thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/56MwY0LAGEc/discussion) that carried the idea further.

The most general unix solution is to have the shebang point to a binary executable. But that executable program could be as simple as a single call to `execl()`. Both threads lead to example C source for a program called gscmd, which is little more than a wrapper to `execv("gs",...)`.